# Calling constructor without assignment; instantiate later

Tags: python, class, reflection, instantiation

Let's say I have this code:

models.py :

```
class Square:
  def __init__(self, name, value):
    self._name = name
    self._value = value
```

mymodule.py :

```
from models import Square
Square('hello', 'there')
```

main.py

```
m = __import__('mymodule')
for i in dir(m):
  if i == 'Square':
     models.append(getattr(m, i))
```

My question is: how do I instantiate the Square I appended (with the arguments I gave in mymodule.py, of course)?

The idea is to instantiate the Square later.

Thanks!

Comment: Where did `models` in main.py come from?

Comment: @martineau Just some python list.

Comment: OK, it was confusing because of the `from models...` you have in mymodule.py and there was no definition for it anywhere in your main.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a flaw in your `mymodule.py` file; you never *store the instance*. Store it in a variable:

```
somevariable = Square('hello', 'there')
```

You cannot just call the constructor and let it dangle.

Looping over the attributes of `mymodule` looking for something named `Square` is not going to get what you want, you'll find the class reference, not the instance.

Perhaps you should be looking for objects of the `Square` type instead:

```
from models import Square

for value in vars(m).itervalues():
    if isinstance(value, Square):
         models.append(value)
```

If you want to avoid having to import the `Square` class, you'd have to test for the type name instead, which is more fragile:

```
for value in vars(m).itervalues():
    if getattr(type(value), '__name__', None) == 'Square':
         models.append(value)
```

If you want to really postpone construction, instead construct it later with a set of pre-set values, use [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from models import Square
from functools import partial

somevariable = partial(Square, 'hello', 'there')
```

If you now import `somevariable` and *call* it, the partial will apply the arguments already passed in and create the instance:

```
instance = somevariable()  # calls Square('hello', 'there')
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just reference the class though? I would be interested in instantiating it with the arguments I gave initially.

Comment: Where do name and value come from though?
I want to use the 'hello' and 'there' that I passed in mymodule.py (that specific call).

Comment: Right, but that would instantiate the Square right there, which I don't want. I want to instantiate it later.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you *are* instantiating it in mymodule.py, but it gets discarded. To stop that you need to store the `Square` created there in something with a name, otherwise it will be garbage-collected since nothing refers to it. Here's what I mean:

mymodule.py :

```
from models import Square
a_square = Square('hello', 'there') # name it
```

Then you can access it directly and more quickly using that name in main.py like this:

main.py

```
models = []
mod = __import__('mymodule')
models.append(vars(mod)['a_square'])  # access it by name
```

Answer (score 0):

**"The idea is to instantiate the Square later."**

You can do that by storing the callable and its arguments.

```
import models
# save as (callable, args, keywords). This does not create a Square
my_model = (model.Squares, ('hello', 'there'), {})
# sometime later, create the square
my_square = my_model[0](*my_model[1], **my_model[2])
```

Or if you want to get super fancy and generate a lot of models, you can make a list:

models.py:

```
class Square(object):
  def __init__(self, name, value):
    self._name = name
    self._value = value

class Round(object):
  def __init__(self, name, value, otherstuff=None):
    self._name = name
    self._value = value
    self._otherstuff = otherstuff
```

mymodule.py:

```
import models
my_models = (
  (models.Square, ('hello', 'there'), {}),
  (models.Round, ('goodbye', 'there'), {'otherstuff':'stuff'})
)
```

main.py

```
m = __import__('mymodule')
models = [model[0](*model[1], **model[2]) for model in m.my_models]
```